# Можно ли вернуть строку подключения из promise-объекта?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть запрос примерно такого вида

```
var locs = Restangular.one('location','list').get();
```

Он возвращает промис. Как мне вытащить из него строку подключения (вида http://host/location/list)? То есть мне еще до фактического отправления запроса надо узнать эту строку. Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: что за объект `Restangular`? что за функция `one`?